# Need Help Joining Multiple tables in Zend framework MySQL INNODB

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db-table

Im currently working with Zend framework.

I'm trying to write a query in MYSQL INNODB database format to return all the provider which match with all the quote criteria values.

Here is a database design of my database.

http://www.iiso.com.au/database.png

So the quote criteria consists of religionTypeId, serviceTypeId, quoteTypeId and postcodeId

The problem im facing is how to join all these tables together (consist of 9 tables) in zend_db_table

Can someone help me out or teach me how to write the MYSQL query ?

THanks you so much in advance :)

Comment: Sorry, But the given URL is not opening.....?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for, see the link below, this is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732699/zend-framework-join-3-tables